# load balanced server farm in php with sql

Tags: php, sql-server, cluster, lighttpd

What is the best configuration for a load balanced server farm for a high demand download web page that uses php and mysql. I have servers that currently use centos with lightppd. 
Has anyone got experience of what software is the best etc, or a good guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use apache for my web server and it works fine.

You have to install another package or service to acquire load balancing. I experience using heartbeat and ldirectord. Please refer here for more instructions and guides. http://www.ultramonkey.org/

Comment: Thanks for that. What would someone like wikipedia or facebook use.

Comment: Please read this one http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-work-nuts-bolts-technology-explained/

Comment: I hope it will help your problem.

Comment: Is ultra monkey a common software tool for load balancing.

Comment: I can't say if it is common but I find it useful because I use for a couple of years and it works fine. Aside from that, it is an opensource software.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to answer that here. Based on the scale of the application described in your [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/394459/recommendations-for-security-on-lamp-server-farm) (now closed) a competent architect would need at least a couple of days of work to come up with an optimal solution in general terms, and at least twice as long to come up with one tailored to your operational setup - and most of that time would be spent gathering information. I wouldn't expect wikipedia or facebook to decide what their server architecture and software should be based on responses to a 3 line question on Stack Overflow / sererfault.

There are very specific reasons why lighttpd might be better than apache (and conversely) and equally for nginx. There are lots of ways to implement load balancing. And there are a number of choices for which database to use (even if you waent to stick with MySQL, you could get your MySQL server from Oracle, MariaDB or Percona).

If one "software is the best" then there wouldn't be so many to choose from.